# TypeError: 'Context' object is not iterable for google cloud function

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

**Can someone help diagnose and correct what the issue is as this error keeps referencing the "Context" object(which I'm theorizing is interpreting the schema_df as that object)?**

I've been trying to deploy a cloud function that works locally on the portion below.

```
def convert_schema(results_df, schema_df):
    """Converts data types in dataframe to match BigQuery destination table"""
    dict(schema_df)
    print(schema_df)
    for k in schema_df: #for each column name in the dictionary, convert the data type in the dataframe
        results_df[k] = results_df[k].astype(schema_df.get(k))
    results_df_transformed = results_df
    print("Updated schema to match BigQuery destination table")
    return results_df_transformed

schema_df = {'_comments': 'object', 
                            '_direction': 'object', 
                            '_fromst': 'object', 
                            '_last_updt': 'datetime64',          
                            '_length': 'float64', 
                            '_lif_lat': 'float64', 
                            '_lit_lat': 'float64', 
                            '_lit_lon': 'float64',
                            '_strheading': 'object', 
                            '_tost': 'object', 
                            '_traffic': 'int64', 
                            'segmentid': 'int64', 
                            'start_lon': 'float64', 
                            'street': 'object'
              }
```

However, it doesn't work and does not recognize the passed in object as an iterable dictionary.

```
                                                              File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 349, in run_background_function
                                                                _function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object)
                                                              File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 215, in invoke_user_function
                                                                return call_user_function(request_or_event)
                                                              File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 212, in call_user_function
                                                                event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context))
                                                              File "/user_code/main.py", line 43, in handler
                                                                results_df_transformed = convert_schema(results_df, schema_df)
                                                              File "/user_code/lib/data_ingestion.py", line 84, in convert_schema
                                                                dict(schema_df)
                                                            TypeError: 'Context' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function that responds to an event (i.e., a "Background Function") needs to have the signature:

```
def my_function(data, context):
    ...
```

where `data` and `context` are provided by the Cloud Functions runtime on every new event.

You probably want to be calling your `convert_schema` function inside the top level background function instead. See "[Writing Background Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background)" for more details.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention this is a pub/sub triggered function. Below is my current state entrypoint function

`def handler(schema_bq, schema_df):`

instead it should be to make sure everything is within the top level background function?

`def handler(data, context):`

Comment: This approach worked. Because of the pubsub trigger, I was mistakenly defining context as a schema object. The below is an example of my solution

`def handler(event, context):` 
  nest the convert_schema function within